# Error in R - Error in t(XXsample) %*% XXsample : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r

Trying to run the below code and got this error -

Error in t(XXsample) %*% XXsample :
requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Can anybody help

'''

```
Diffsgd = array(,dim=1000)
Dsgd = matrix(100,1)
wtsgd= matrix(100,1)
wtsgd[1:100]=1
wt_prevsgd= matrix(100,1)
wt_prevsgd[1:100]=1
Xsample= as.numeric(matrix(100,100))
XXsample= as.numeric(matrix(100,100))
Ysample=as.numeric(matrix(100,1))
for (i in 1:1000){
    Xsample=train[sample(nrow(train),100),]
    XXsample=Xsample[,1:100]
    Ysample=Xsample[,101]

    Dsgd = ((t(XXsample) %*% XXsample) %*% wtsgd) - (t(XXsample) %*% Ysample)
    wtsgd = wtsgd - (0.00001) * Dsgd
    Diffsgd[i] = rowSums((wtsgd - wml)^2)
    wt_prevsgd=wtsgd
}
```

'''

Comment: what is `train`? Check out how to create matrices vs vectors

Comment: Thanks Onyambu. You pointed at the right place. 'train' was a read file object. I did as.matrix() to it and it worked.